# How to handle Form caption right click

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I'd like a context menu on the caption bar right click

any tips/samples pref in c# ?

UPDATE - for various reasons, right click on the form won't work because the form is not empty and the form is composited dynamically so....

Comment: Right click on the form or the caption of the form??

Comment: there's no mouseclick on clicking the caption, as far as i can tell, you have to hook into the win32 to handle the non client area events which i haven't done in ages hence....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by trapping the WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN notification that Windows sends when the user right-clicks the title bar.  The control class does not have an event for it, you'll need to override WndProc().  Here's an example form, you'll need to add a ContextMenuStrip:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected void OnTitlebarClick(Point pos) {
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(pos);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        const int WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN = 0xa4;
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN) { 
            var pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
            OnTitlebarClick(pos);
            return;
        }                                           
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx) how to handle right-clicks on Windows Forms controls.  Controls, including Forms, inherit the MouseClick event.

[MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs_members.aspx) will tell you what button was clicked through the [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.button.aspx) property.  Have a look at the [MouseButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mousebuttons.aspx) Enumeration.

Comment: I see.  Unfortunately there is no MousePreview like there is a KeyPreview, so I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

if you handle the form mouse-click, you can then use the following code:

```
  private void Dialog_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
      {                                
          this.Text = "new caption text";
      }
  }
```

But you'll have to make sure that you generate this event for the top-level control on a form. For instance if you have a group box on the form, it will receive the mouse-click events rather than the form itself, for the areas of the form that are under the group box.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a menu managed by Windows when you right-click the titlebar.

Do you want to replace it completely?

If you want to add to it you will have to use the Win32 API and interop and you will have to subclass the form.

See the AppendMenu() function.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use p-invoke to do this.  There is a really great example at [Here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/03/04/Add-System-Menu-Items-to-a-Form-using-Windows-API.aspx)
You can see from the example you will need to manually mimic the event handlers, but this is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can override WndProc of the form and capture the WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN message:

```
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
   {
       const int WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN = 0xA4;

       if (m.Msg == WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Caption right clicked!");
       }
       else
       {
           base.WndProc(ref m);
       }
   }
```

This code will suppress the window's context menu, however.  You may not wish this.  The WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN message will also be sent if you right click the window borders as well.  You may not desire this either.